# PHP Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, fetch

After uploading the site to my web server I get this message:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource 
in /home1/m1k3ey/public_html/MikeyDev.com/teamdesire/playersheet.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource 
in /home1/m1k3ey/public_html/MikeyDev.com/teamdesire/playersheet.php on line 9
```

My PHP version is:

`PHP Version 5.2.17`

I cant see where im going wrong in my code, can anyone please assist:

```
          mysql_select_db('teamdesire', $link);
          $query = "SELECT * FROM playershowercase";
          $result = mysql_query($query,$link);
          $row = array();
Line 8 >  while($row[] = mysql_fetch_array($result));
Line 9 >  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
          $random = rand(0,$count-1);
```

Comment: PHP version into your server ???

Comment: As per the usual for your error message: Your query has failed somehow, your code blindly assumes success, and blundered onwards.

Comment: @MikeyT - have you tried `$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die (mysql_error());` ? Or `var_dump($result`?

Comment: Yes ive tried that, in my error log it says exactly the same error which is displayed on screen

Comment: @MikeyT - and what does `var_dump($result)` show?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following?

```
      mysql_select_db('teamdesire', $link);
      $query = "SELECT * FROM playershowercase";
      $result = mysql_query($query,$link);
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
      $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
      $random = rand(0,$count-1);
```

Or

```
      mysql_select_db('teamdesire', $link);
      $query = "SELECT * FROM playershowercase";
      $result = mysql_query($query,$link);
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
      $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
      $random = rand(0,$count-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible error sources:

- Db is not running on specified socket or port.
- Insufficient permissions on the table or database.
- Incorrect login credentials.
- Table does not exist or is misspelled.

**Echo line per line when you troubleshoot.**

```
is_resource($link) or die('Could not connect');
mysql_query(...);
echo mysql_error();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
          mysql_select_db('teamdesire', $link);
          $query = "SELECT * FROM playershowercase";
          $result = mysql_query($query,$link);
          $row = array();
          while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          $row[]=$result;
          }
          $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
          $random = rand(0,$count-1);
```

Comment: I get the same error again unfortunately